# What is the title of the Wizard of Oz sequel in which people are weighed to determine the ruler?

Tags: story-identification, the-wizard-of-oz

I'm looking for a recent book title in the Oz series. I remember the plot was the inhabitants of Oz are tired of Ozma as ruler, so she proposes a contest.

The inhabitants would get weighed, with the fattest becoming ruler of Oz.

I  read it in the late 90s or early 2000s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Wonder City of Oz, by John R. Neill

[image]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonder_City_of_Oz):

> Yet her ambition lures her into running against Ozma in an Ozlection to become ruler of the Land of Oz.
> It is clear that Ozma will win any fair election by a landslide — but a landslide is a terribly dangerous thing to have in the Emerald City. So Prof. Wogglebug cooks up a more random choice, in which citizens are weighed on scales to determine their votes.

Found by looking through the list of Oz books on Wikipedia, and then finding one that appeared to match the description of 'Ozma not becoming the ruler anymore', and went to that page... and voila.